# The range of attributive

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context, conjunctions

I have a clause from DirectX SDK as below:

> The position, velocity, and orientation of sound sources and listeners
>   in 3D space are represented by Cartesian coordinates

what's the range of world position, velocity and orientation? do they decorate only sound sources? or they decorate listeners too?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean "do they *modify*"? ... If so, it's the other way round: all three appear (by ordinary rules of English syntax) to be *modified by* "of sources" and "[of] listeners".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mathematical parenthesis to clarify, the sentence can be broken up as follows:

*The (position, velocity, and orientation) of (sound sources and listeners) in 3D space are represented by Cartesian coordinates*

Therefore:

- the position, velocity and orientation of sound sources are represented by Cartesian co-ordinates.
- the position, velocity and orientation of listeners are represented by Cartesian co-ordinates.

I personally would have written it like this:

*Cartesian co-ordinates are used to represent the position, velocity and orientation in 3D space of both sound sources and listeners.*